# Creating a watchdog service with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to make a watchdog service on Windows Server using PowerShell? If yes, how can I do it?

I am trying to create a watchdog service. It will control services and installation code inside the watchdog and check it if it is working or not. Could you share any material?

Comment: plz guys dont  vote it minus i cant find answer i searched a lot

Comment: Please read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Did you try anything? Provide some code please

Answer (score 3):

You won't be able to create a service as such, but you could have a scheduled task that runs on server startup (as NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM) that executes a PowerShell script which is essentially a loop that repeats forever. Inside the loop you would, periodically, get the state of other services you're interested in monitoring and start/stop them as required based on what you want to happen.

Example code (though there are probably better ways of writing this and it has no error handling):

```
# This file contains a two-column list like so:
# servicename,desiredstate
# CryptSvc,running
# AdobeARMservice,stopped
$services = import-csv c:\scripts\services.csv

$loop = $true # loop forever
do
{
    foreach($service in $services)
    {
        $svc = Get-Service $svc.servicename
        if($svc.Status.ToString().ToLower() -ne $service.desiredstate)
        {
            switch($service.desiredstate)
            {
                "stopped"
                {
                    $svc.Stop()
                    break
                }

                "running"
                {
                    $svc.Start()
                    break
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 300 # wait 5 minutes after each loop has ended
} while ($loop -eq $true)
```

Comment: You could also just schedule the task to run every 5 minutes